# No resource identifier found for attribute 'startcolor' in package 'android'

Tags: java, xml, visual-studio, xamarin, button

I have two errors:
- No resource identifier found for attribute 'startcolor' in package 'android'
- No resource identifier found for attribute 'endcolor' in package 'android'
The following is the code from an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
  <item>
    <shape **android:shape**="rectangle">
      <corners **android:radius**="50dp"/>
      <solid **android:color**="#FDFDFE"/>
      <size **android:height**="35dp"/>
      <gradient **android:startcolor**="#71DA98" **android:endcolor**="#56C5ED"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

My aim is to have a gradient colour for a button in the android login page.
By the way, the bolded text are underlined with warnings stating the attribute is not declared. I am using xamarin. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Android attributes should be defined using [**lowerCamelCase**](http://wiki.c2.com/?LowerCamelCase). Thus your attributes should be `android:startColor` and `android:endColor`.

Comment: oh thank you very much. The problem has been solved using ur resolve. I appreciate ur help.